# Remove all objects in tabBarController and later restore the default tabBar?

Tags: ios, tabbarcontroller

I am looking for the behaviour in iOS to remove all the items/objects in my tabBar but also be able to restore them later on. To remove all items/objects the following code is working fine:

```
NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
[controllers removeAllObjects];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:controllers animated:YES];
```

But how do I restore the default tabBar once again after it being removed? Try to be specific.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// backup the current viewcontrollers
NSArray *viewControllerBackup = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;

// remove tabs
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:@[] animated:YES];

// restore tabs
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllerBackup animated:YES];
```

Comment: This code will remove the tabBar items but not restore them :/ Is it becasue of an animation problem? With other words can you make tabBar items appear from nowhere without having to reload the whole viewController?

Comment: it does. you have to backup the viewcontrollers at a "safe" place. take a look at my sample project: https://github.com/slotti85/RestoreTabs